# What should I keep in mind while developing a game for Steam?

Tags: steam

I recently did the programming on a [game](http://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/576557) that was just released and i've decided that for my next project I want to do something a little bigger scale.  I plan to develop a game to be sold on Steam, it will be 3D.  I've done large-scale games in Flash and a small game in C++ written with OpenGL.  I realize that flash-based games can be submitted to Steam but I'd like for it to be written in some variation of C.  I'm looking for information on a couple things.

1. What engine should I use? Ideally I'd like it to work on both Mac and PC. Seeing as it would be released on Steam, I'd like to use the Source Engine but I'm worried about having to pay licensing fees when I don't plan to make loads of money on it - it's mainly for the experience and as a resume builder.
2. What sorts of things should I keep in mind when developing so that when, and if, it gets accepted, the process of adding the [Steam-specific functionality](http://www.steampowered.com/steamworks/FAQ.php#Technical) will be less painful.

Comment: This appears to be a "which technology to use" question and beyond that it's an open-ended list of opinions type question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it matters which engine you use; from what I've seen, steam accepts games that are of high enough quality (polish) and are relevant to the steam customer base.

Winning IGF or some such also helps.

Comment: Agreed - off the top of my head, I can think of games on Steam that are based on Flash, Java, XNA, and any number of proprietary game engines.

Comment: Steam requires the game to be self sufficient. You are not allowed to make the game a program that opens their browser and takes them to the the browser game site. They require you to roll an integrated browser to do that.

Comment: *cough*uplay*cough* =)